# slug 404 not found in django

Tags: python, django

Here is my views.py

```
from .models import Post,Author


def posts_list(request):
   all_posts = Post.objects.all()
   context = {
       'all_posts': all_posts
   }
   return render(request,"post_list.html",context)


def posts_detail(request, slug):
   unique_post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
   context = {
       'post': unique_post,
   }
   return render(request,"posts_detail.html",context)
```

and my urls.py is:

```
from django.urls import path
from posts import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('post/',views.posts_list),
    path('post/(<slug:slug>/', views.posts_detail,name='post'),
    ]
```

every time i go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/first 
i get 404 page not found  i tired reloading my django server and find others solution too but i cannot figure out what the problem upto https://http://127.0.0.1:8000/post the route is working but after slug not working please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: path('post/<slug:slug>/', views.posts_detail,name='post'), remove the bracket before slug

Comment: @bmons ohh my silly mistake can't figure out though thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove bracket `(` before the `slug`

change this

```
path('post/(<slug:slug>/', views.posts_detail,name='post'),
```

to

```
path('post/<slug:slug>/', views.posts_detail,name='post'),
```

Thanks